# class inheritance cant get my Equals() to work

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class:

```
  class Stock : Product
  {
  }
```

And in that class i have made a `Equals` method:

```
  public bool Equals(Product p)
  {
      return (p.Id == this.Id);
  }
```

But it's not working. It tells me that `Equals`:

> **Warning  1** 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Stock.Equals(WindowsFormsApplication1.Product)' hides inherited member 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Product.Equals(WindowsFormsApplication1.Product)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

```
C:\Users\tom\Desktop\uni\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Stock.cs    36  21  WindowsFormsApplication1
```

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override `Equals` method, which is already used in Product Class.

```
public override bool Equals(Product p)
{
    return (p.Id == this.Id);
}
```

Or use `new` keyword. But I don't think 'new' is what you want.

Comment: Even if `Product` didn't use `Equals` it still needs the `override` keyword. It is used in `System.Object`

Comment: i did that and got this Error 1 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Stock.Equals(WindowsFormsApplication1.Product)': cannot override inherited member 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Product.Equals(WindowsFormsApplication1.Product)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override C:\Users\tom\Desktop\uni\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Stock.cs 36 30 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: Make the `Product.Equals` method override.

If you want to override `System.Object.Equals` you should 
write: 
    public override bool Equals(Object p) 
not
    public override bool Equals(Product p)

Comment: Or make `Product.Equals` method virtual.

It is all depends on if you want to override `System.Object.Equals`..

Comment: If you make `Product.Equals` virtual, it is hiding the `object.Equals` method, not overriding. `override` keyword allows more inheritance in the chain already. If you want to stop the inheritance chain for this method you can add the keyword `sealed`

Comment: Not, it won't hide the `Object.Equals` method, because they have different signatures (see their parameters).

Answer (score 5):

`Equals` in inherited from `System.Object`. All objects inherit this class.

```
public override bool Equals(object p)
{    
    return ((Stock)p.Id == this.Id);
}
```

EDIT:
In order to override, the parameter needs to be of the same type. In `object` it is of type object. If you declared this method in `Product` like:

```
public bool Equals(Product p)
{    
    return (p.Id == this.Id);
}
```

then you have to change the parameter type in Stock.Equals to Product. However, this Equals method is hiding `object.Equals` and I think this is not a good design. If you want to use the `Equals` method right, you need to override because many components call this method when they search in a collection and they will call `object.Equals` anyway and won't use your code if you use hiding and not overriding.
If those methods are something internal in your project and not related to `object.Equals` mechanism, choose a different name for this method to avoid confusion.

Comment: Agree with you about `isn't a good design`. Richter wrote about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning, it will work as expected. Since your product class defines `Equals`, the child class `Stock` is defining its own `Equals` method.

Assuming you have the following class setup:

```
class Product
{
    public bool Equals(Product p)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
  class Stock : Product
    {
        public bool Equals(Product p)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here you will get the warning:

> Stock.Equals(Product)' hides inherited member
>   'Product.Equals(Product)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

You can simply use the `new` keyword to tell the compiler that Yes the hiding is intended. 
So you method inside stock `class` would be would be:

```
new public bool Equals(Product p)
{
    return true;
}
```

You may wanna see [new modifier - msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an `bool Equals(Product)` method already defined on `Product`, make it virtual and override it in `Stock`.

Comment: It's not necessary to define Equals as `virtual` in `Product` class. `Object` class already does.

Comment: The Equals method in `Object` is for an `Object` parameter, so it is necessary, unless we are overriding `bool Equals(Object)`, which we aren't

Answer (score 0):

You need to put override to implict declare the replacement of the parent method:

```
public override bool Equals(Product p)     
{          
   return (p.Id == this.Id);      
}
```

This warning help the coder to avoid unwanted override of parent method.